# How to display data in a matplot plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to make an interactive plot in the `jupyter notebook` but i don't know exactly how to implement it. Having a dataframe i run a simple regression that is then plotted to see the distribution. I'd like to be able to hover one of the points and get data associated with this point. How can i do that? Right now i can only produce a static plot
[image]

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

net = pd.read_csv("network_ver_64.csv")
net = net[net.AWDT12 > 0]

x = net.LOAD_DAILY.values
y = net.AWDT12.values
x_lenght = int(x.shape[0])
y_lenght = int(y.shape[0])
x = x.reshape(x_lenght, 1)
y = y.reshape(y_lenght,1)
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(x, y)

plt.scatter(x, y,  color='black')
plt.plot(x, regr.predict(x), color='blue', linewidth=1)
plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())
plt.show()
```

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot get hover functionality with matplotlib. You have to try [d3.js](https://d3js.org/) or [bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/)

Comment: @MainulIslam nice. yeah i didn't know about those modules, ill check them out to learn about them

Comment: [Plot.ly](https://plot.ly/python/) is also worth checking out for what you want to do.

Comment: @Mainul There is an in-built hover functionality in matplotlib, which is also available in jupyter with the `notebook` backend. Apart from that any kind of interaction may be achieved programmatically. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all it's clear that the `%matplotlib inline` backend does not allow for interaction, as it is inline (in the sense that the plots are images).

However even in the notebook you can get interaction using the `%matplotlib notebook` backend. A basic hover took is already implemented: Moving the mouse in the canvas shows the current mouse position in data coordinates in the lower right corner.

[image]

Of course you can obtain more sophisticated functionality by writing some custom code. E.g. we can modify the [picking example](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/event_handling.html#simple-picking-example) a little bit as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title('click on points')

line, = ax.plot(np.random.rand(100), 'o', picker=5)  # 5 points tolerance
text = ax.text(0,0,"")
def onpick(event):
    thisline = event.artist
    xdata = thisline.get_xdata()
    ydata = thisline.get_ydata()
    ind = event.ind
    text.set_position((xdata[ind], ydata[ind]))
    text.set_text(zip(xdata[ind], ydata[ind]))

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

plt.show()
```

This now shows the data coordinates of the point the mouse has clicked.

[image]

You're pretty free to adapt this to any case you like and make it more pretty using the standard matplotlib tools.