# Matplotlib - How to show coordinates in scatterplot?

Tags: matplotlib, coordinates, show, scatter-plot, interactive

I'm fairly new to matplotlib but I thought that when I hover on a point on my scatter plot, it would show the coordinates. However, that doesn't seem to be the case?

Comment: No, this feature is not automatically implemented in matplotlib. plot.ly does have the hovering by default. For matplotlib, you may look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42703278/how-to-display-data-in-a-matplot-plot) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908636/possible-to-make-labels-appear-when-hovering-over-a-point-in-matplotlib) for a start in matplotlib. Since the question is too unspecific, we might also close it as duplicate of one of those.

Comment: Possibly the closest to what you want is [this official example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/cursor_demo.html).